# Can my macbook HDD be used in a windows desktop?

Tags: macbook-pro, hard-drive, sata

It seems there is a formatting issue / dead hdd in my macbook, as I have the infamous ? despite ensuring a good connection with the sata cable. Is it ok to plug the 2.5" macbook hdd into the standard sata & sata power cables on my windows desktop and check it out from there?

If it is working, will it show on windows?

I have no other mac to use or a sata-usb enclosure...

Thanks,

nuggetbram

Comment: Please add your MacBook model (e.g. MacBook Pro mid 2012) and the system version (e.g. 10.9.5) to your question

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to boot to the recovery partition ..Boot with Cmd-R held down, and use disk utility to check/repair the filesystem

In the windows PC the disk should spin up but Windows will not be able to recognise the HFS+ filesystem on it, and will offer to format it for you. Don't let it!
Paragon Software produce a tool [HFS+ for Windows](http://www.paragon-software.com/home/hfs-windows/) which will allow it to mount the disk.

This will probably fail in strange and interesting ways if it is in fact corrupted. Another option might be some of the Mac Disk recovery programs e.g. [Diskwarrior](http://www.paragon-software.com/home/hfs-windows/) or [TechToolPro](https://www.micromat.com/products/techtool-pro)

Comment: When booting into the disk utility / recovery, the disk does not show up, but there is a disk called "Media" that I don't recall ever seeing before, with a size of 0kb. Does this imply that the disk is functional or dead? It could be either...